# static keyword before variable in a method

Tags: php, static

I found the following method and I don't know what the `static` keyword does at that point. The variable is initialized with `[]` so it's empty anytime the method is called anyways.

What does the `static` keyword do at this point?

```
public function getSomething($entity)
{
    static $collection = [];
    if (!$collection[$entity->getPrimaryKey()]) {
        $collection[$entity->getPrimaryKey()] = 'something';
    }

    return $this->doCollection($collection);
}
```

Comment:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: Or [the second example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508374/2370483)

Comment: > 20 years in PHP programming and I've never seen someone really use this since OOP is a thing

Answer (score -2):

declaring properties or methods as static allows you to access them without needing to instantiate the class.

Comment: It's neither a property nor a method.