# get function in laravel returns null after setting the public var

Tags: php, laravel, oop

i defined a public variable in laravel class then in search function i set this variable to the search data to use it in another function using $this->_lastSearch = $request->all() it didn't work, so i used a set function to set the value and a get function to get the value of the variable..

then in another function i used the get function to get the value of the variable as img below

[image: code]

[image: code2]

[image: code3]

i expected to get the value from set function

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put up pictures of code; code is text and belongs in your question in a codeblock

Comment: Do not share code or anything similar as images (except some errors) due to the image going down in a near future rendering this question unreadable and not understandable...

Comment: try to use dd() and show the results

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A variable in an instance is not persistent. When you construct a new controller, it won't have the defined variable from another instance.

We can't see where you're using your `getPaginatedSearchResult` method, but most likely you're not calling it in the same lifecycle as the one where you're setting the `$_lastSearch`. Since it's a Laravel controller, you're probably calling it from a route (perhaps an AJAX request?), which means it will construct a new controller. If you wish to keep data persistent, use static variables. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508298/14793358) shows how that works.

Comment: I added the code below, pls check it